# Create a persistent store for Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I did the tutorial on apples site, the [Core Data tutorial for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305) and i did this tutorial about 3 times to see if i was mistaken, But when i finish the tutorial, it says that the app should work and be able to add `Events` to the table view, but when i press the `+` button, the app crashes and the console says: `Cannot do save operation. There is no persistent store`

How could i fix this? I checked my code and i have everything!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have Locations.xcdatamodel file in your project???

Comment: the sample code is working fine

Comment: Yeah i have the data model file! and hmm.. i tried it multiple times, it still isnt working!!